# Drawing into a "position: fixed" overlay, aligned with scrolling inline content

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-position

I have a long webpage with some number of inline `<figure/>` elements requiring 2D or 3D HTMLCanvasElement to display. For performance reasons not in scope here, it is not practical to put an HTMLCanvasElement into each  `<figure/>`, and instead I have single HTMLCanvasElement as a `position: fixed` overlay.

On each frame (using `requestAnimationFrame`) I use `figure.getBoundingClientRect()` to find the position and size of each figure relative to the window, and then draw into the areas of the canvas overlay that overlap with a `<figure/>` behind it. For simplicity, each figure is just a circle.

This works fine while the page is static, but I'm seeing very **inconsistent results in different browsers while scrolling**. In Firefox, content drawn to the canvas aligns perfectly with the inline page behind it. In Chrome and (sometimes?) Safari, content drawn to the canvas lags behind the inline page slightly – see in the demo, in which the circle doesn't stay within the border while scrolling.

Goals:

1. One (1) HTMLCanvasElement
2. Overlay content is stable relative to inline figure borders while scrolling
3. Overlay content is stable relative to window while scrolling through the larger `position: sticky` figure (i.e. no movement is visible)

**Question:** Why is this not working in Chrome or Safari, and can it be fixed with a different CSS or JavaScript implementation?

**Screenshot during scroll:**

[image: misaligned figure]

```js
const figures = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('figure'));
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

animate();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight) {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "crimson";

  for (const figure of figures) {
    drawFigure(figure);
  }
}

function drawFigure(figure) {
  const {
    left,
    top,
    width,
    height
  } = figure.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (top > innerHeight) return;

  const size = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 5;
  const x = left + width / 2;
  const y = top + height / 2;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Courier;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

main {
  margin: 2em auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 2em;
}

p {
  text-indent: 2.5em;
}

figure {
  background: mintcream;
  border: 5px dashed aquamarine;
  margin: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

figure.inline {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0.5em 2em;
}

figure.inline:nth-of-type(odd) {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
}

figure.inline:nth-of-type(even) {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.full {
  height: 500vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.full>figure.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px dashed crimson;
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  font-style: italic;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Scrolling Inline Content + Fixed Overlay</h1>
  <p>
    Tart sweet roll jujubes wafer halvah chocolate bar muffin. Pie sweet roll brownie chocolate liquorice oat cake gingerbread. Powder topping shortbread jujubes oat cake shortbread jelly. Macaroon chupa chups sweet roll danish powder carrot cake tart bonbon.
    Sweet gummies chocolate bar sugar plum chocolate lollipop sweet. Caramels marshmallow sugar plum apple pie tart soufflé biscuit halvah tart. Topping danish toffee chocolate pastry. Shortbread donut oat cake chocolate bar biscuit marshmallow macaroon
    wafer. Danish chocolate bar cupcake marzipan jelly beans wafer. Bear claw jelly toffee topping cotton candy pudding oat cake bonbon. Caramels powder brownie donut carrot cake cake ice cream. Jelly chocolate bar dragée gingerbread cotton candy fruitcake
    shortbread. Soufflé cake danish fruitcake fruitcake cake marzipan.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cheesecake sweet sweet cookie soufflé jelly beans. Caramels chupa chups chocolate cake shortbread cupcake donut muffin macaroon croissant. Brownie sweet chupa chups sweet roll toffee. Tiramisu marzipan liquorice candy powder pudding toffee wafer sesame
    snaps. Powder lollipop cake toffee chupa chups. Halvah dragée shortbread cookie ice cream. Lemon drops bear claw muffin powder gummies tootsie roll powder gummi bears. Toffee sweet cake gingerbread tootsie roll marzipan lollipop jelly-o pudding. Cake
    cake sugar plum pie tiramisu chocolate cake jelly beans candy canes oat cake. Cupcake chocolate wafer powder powder. Tiramisu topping sweet ice cream sugar plum candy canes danish pudding. Fruitcake candy canes chocolate cake oat cake croissant cookie.
    Cake pie lemon drops ice cream apple pie cookie marzipan tiramisu caramels.
  </p>
  <figure class="inline"></figure>
  <p>
    Fruitcake topping cookie soufflé toffee candy bonbon. Powder sweet gummi bears ice cream pudding halvah tootsie roll tart dragée. Danish tootsie roll jelly beans bear claw chocolate cake cheesecake gingerbread tiramisu oat cake. Chocolate bar candy canes
    shortbread donut jujubes bear claw. Tootsie roll toffee soufflé liquorice marshmallow. Powder cotton candy marzipan soufflé macaroon dragée lollipop chocolate bar gingerbread. Oat cake chocolate cake jelly beans cotton candy pudding. Tiramisu candy
    canes jelly-o croissant brownie. Chocolate bar icing fruitcake sesame snaps powder.
  </p>
  <p>
    Halvah cookie cheesecake donut lollipop pudding candy tart. Gummies biscuit dragée cotton candy chocolate cake toffee lemon drops. Chocolate bar oat cake gummi bears tart toffee gingerbread sugar plum donut jelly-o. Apple pie pastry sugar plum jujubes
    lollipop candy sesame snaps lemon drops caramels. Carrot cake pie oat cake powder dragée chocolate cake sweet roll marzipan. Lollipop lollipop tiramisu bonbon pudding tootsie roll. Dessert caramels sweet sugar plum cheesecake cake. Dragée cookie cake
    pastry candy.
  </p>
  <figure class="inline"></figure>
  <p>
    Oat cake chocolate bar donut cotton candy soufflé halvah. Biscuit jujubes ice cream brownie cheesecake brownie dragée lollipop dragée. Dragée sweet powder shortbread croissant croissant sweet roll cheesecake. Wafer marshmallow cheesecake jujubes tootsie
    roll bonbon croissant carrot cake. Chocolate shortbread shortbread cheesecake pie chocolate sweet. Sweet roll chupa chups candy muffin macaroon topping cake. Candy icing donut shortbread macaroon fruitcake tart muffin. Caramels candy canes sweet pie
    cheesecake. Topping powder soufflé chocolate cake liquorice powder danish.
  </p>
  <p>
    Macaroon dessert gummies cake tiramisu candy chocolate. Cookie powder donut jelly beans ice cream dragée pie. Marshmallow fruitcake macaroon icing jujubes croissant. Candy canes topping dessert candy canes apple pie pie cake. Tiramisu caramels tiramisu
    brownie croissant. Chocolate cake marshmallow apple pie candy danish shortbread jujubes chupa chups caramels. Wafer chupa chups candy canes fruitcake biscuit fruitcake gingerbread pudding.
  </p>
  <p>
    Jelly beans danish danish chupa chups cookie cheesecake powder. Danish lemon drops gingerbread chupa chups cheesecake macaroon danish tart sweet roll. Biscuit jelly beans gummi bears sesame snaps liquorice halvah wafer. Gingerbread halvah cotton candy
    apple pie carrot cake sweet roll gingerbread pastry. Jelly beans sesame snaps tootsie roll cupcake chocolate bar chocolate cake sesame snaps. Carrot cake powder cake ice cream ice cream chocolate cake. Carrot cake gummies biscuit powder cake shortbread.
    Tiramisu liquorice bonbon jelly-o danish tootsie roll lollipop brownie brownie. Carrot cake jelly-o danish bear claw tootsie roll sesame snaps caramels pie gummies.
  </p>
  <div class="full">
    <figure class="sticky"></figure>
  </div>
  <p>
    Chocolate bar shortbread jelly-o cake pastry cake chocolate cake. Pudding pastry caramels sweet bear claw marshmallow bear claw. Sesame snaps gummies topping brownie macaroon pastry. Dragée macaroon danish apple pie chocolate bar shortbread muffin. Dessert
    jelly apple pie biscuit dessert. Tart chocolate sugar plum cheesecake topping. Pastry toffee donut candy canes marshmallow cake lemon drops. Cotton candy cake tart carrot cake topping tart cake gummi bears cake. Brownie sweet croissant jujubes sweet
    roll jelly beans jelly fruitcake cupcake. Tart danish danish jujubes pastry tiramisu tart dragée dessert.
  </p>
  <figure class="inline"></figure>

  <p>
    Croissant powder danish muffin sugar plum gingerbread cake chocolate cake. Chocolate cake biscuit wafer tootsie roll marshmallow sesame snaps soufflé pudding. Bonbon pie oat cake shortbread cheesecake ice cream. Chupa chups oat cake caramels cupcake chocolate.
    Carrot cake candy canes wafer soufflé chocolate bar cake jelly beans. Caramels lollipop jelly beans marzipan gingerbread brownie marshmallow. Candy canes ice cream gummi bears candy ice cream chocolate bar ice cream. Sugar plum danish fruitcake biscuit
    cheesecake chocolate bar.
  </p>
  <p>
    Carrot cake powder brownie gummi bears marzipan carrot cake. Tootsie roll cake gummies dragée chupa chups oat cake tart. Dragée lemon drops cake icing jelly beans cookie chocolate cake. Biscuit sweet roll sesame snaps tart pudding jelly ice cream. Fruitcake
    danish tootsie roll marshmallow fruitcake halvah. Cake lemon drops carrot cake chocolate cake bonbon sweet carrot cake caramels.
  </p>
  <p>
    Biscuit pudding macaroon cookie muffin jelly. Candy canes lollipop dragée sweet carrot cake candy cotton candy. Sweet roll dragée dragée cheesecake sweet gingerbread oat cake danish. Shortbread jelly-o cake bear claw gummi bears sesame snaps. Shortbread
    pastry liquorice tiramisu bonbon. Lollipop gingerbread gummi bears sweet liquorice gummies shortbread biscuit sweet. Fruitcake donut chocolate cake wafer danish. Chocolate fruitcake powder bonbon tiramisu lollipop.
  </p>
  <p>
    Chocolate cake chocolate candy liquorice liquorice jelly beans carrot cake candy canes cheesecake. Lollipop chocolate bar gummi bears candy canes chocolate cake oat cake halvah bonbon. Cupcake biscuit biscuit halvah brownie candy oat cake lollipop. Gummi
    bears sweet pastry marshmallow jujubes donut lollipop candy dragée. Oat cake carrot cake donut halvah dragée biscuit brownie gummies. Liquorice chupa chups sweet candy canes chocolate cake. Croissant cupcake bonbon gingerbread sweet lemon drops tootsie
    roll. Macaroon cake chupa chups sweet jelly beans sesame snaps bonbon cotton candy ice cream. Dessert marzipan lemon drops muffin chocolate liquorice. Chupa chups biscuit bear claw bear claw liquorice sugar plum fruitcake. Gummi bears donut chocolate
    shortbread chocolate bar halvah gingerbread. Cotton candy cheesecake croissant donut jelly jelly. Chocolate sweet roll fruitcake ice cream muffin chupa chups croissant. Sugar plum jujubes cupcake cotton candy marshmallow sesame snaps dragée candy.
  </p>
  <hr>
  <footer>
    Filler text by <a href="https://cupcakeipsum.com/" target="_blank">Cupcake Ipsum</a>.
  </footer>
</main>

<canvas></canvas>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/donmccurdy/9sg1fr3p/

Comment: The demo in your question renders fine for me in both Chrome and Firefox - although the animation is over so quickly I can't test scrolling and animating at the same time

Comment: Thanks for your response. There's no animation as such, the page should *look* as if it simply contains inline images. But while scrolling, the circles shift outside the borders in ways that an image would not. It's possible this is platform-specific — I'm testing on macOS 14, and seeing the problem in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Understood - it may be a Mac-related issue then as I was testing on Windows.

Comment: I can BARELY see it on my windows computer, but I think this is somewhat intentional. If it did what you wanted, it would need to recalculate the position about 4-5 times per second, which is terrible for performance while scrolling. If you stopped using `requestAnimationFrame` it would probably refresh more often, but at the expense of major performance loss.

Comment: I suppose you could try messing with the `scroll-behavior`. Maybe `scroll-behavior: smooth;` would give you better results, or something.

Comment: I think you're right that this is related to browser scroll smoothing, but `scroll-behavior: smooth;` does not affect scrolling triggered by the user (only scrolling by programmatic means), and has no effect here.

Comment: As a test, I tried caching the results of getBoundingClientRect() and offsetting them by `window.scrollY` in `requestAnimationFrame`, which didn't change the result. Note that nothing in this demo moves! Figures remain inline, the canvas remains at `position: fixed; top: 0;`. It's just that when drawing to canvas, my data on where figures are, relative to the viewport, is outdated during scroll.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE:** I am posting a solution to my own question, but will leave this open and 'unanswered' for a bit in the hopes that someone else can come up with a better solution, or explain why any of this happens! Thanks.

I've worked around the problem, by dividing it into two cases and using JavaScript to switch between them.

1. **No figure occupies full screen height.** Use `position: absolute`, updating `top: XXpx` every frame, to keep the canvas pinned *relative to the document body* and its inline contents. The viewport now pulls away from the canvas slightly during scrolling, so we extend the canvas by 100px as a buffer.
2. **At least one figure occupies full screen height.** Use `position: sticky; top: 0;` to keep the figure from appearing to shift *relative to the viewport* during scroll.

For my purposes, these two cases are mutually exclusive. There's still a small shift in the canvas when we transition between the two, but it's much less noticeable than the original issue.

Updates to the canvas work something like this:

```js
if (figures.some(isFullWindow)) {
    canvas.style.position = 'fixed';
    canvas.style.top = (-PAD) + 'px';
    canvas.style.left = (-PAD) + 'px';
} else {
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    canvas.style.top = (window.scrollY - PAD) + 'px';
    canvas.style.left = (-PAD) + 'px';
}

function isFullWindow(figure) {
  const {top, bottom} = figure.getBoundingClientRect();
  const _isFullView = top <= 0 && bottom >= innerHeight;
  return _isFullView;
}
```

An additional container around the canvas is required, to support `position: sticky` mode.